# Spark-Cassandra Maven project with java source making scala-lib calls

Tags: java, scala, maven, cassandra, apache-spark

I am fairly new to both Spark and Cassandra and need some guidance.  I am setting up a maven project that uses Spark v1.3.1 and Cassandra v2.0.14.  I am attempting the following:

1) Make a connection with Oracle DB using the following approach for data input; leveraging DataFrames new to Spark 1.3.0: http://www.sparkexpert.com/2015/03/28/loading-database-data-into-spark-using-data-sources-api/

2) Using spark-cassandra-connector to make the connection between the latter; found on github.

3) Once i have the DB data in DataFrame i should be able to convert to JavaRDD type and push to Cassandra keyspace as illustrated here: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/accessing-cassandra-from-spark-in-java

4) In short: [Oracle DB]<---[Spark]---[spark-cassandra-connector]--->[Cassandra]

The problem i'm having comes during (step 1 from above) the Scala-lib call in my Java code; more specifically during load function call: DataFrame jdbcDF = sqlContext.load(“jdbc”, options);

Runtime Error:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce$class”

The above errors comes despite having tried several different version of the recommended 2.10.X Scala in my pom.xml file.  From my prior research i'm thinking it might be a Spark-Scala compatibility issue.  I've also read that i need to include the scala-lib.jar in my classpath but i am not certain how to do this with maven. Any ideas on any of this?  I've included the pom.xml and java code below:

POM.XML

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.dev</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-cassandra</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SPARK-CASSANDRA</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.35</version>
        </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
     <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
     <version>11.2.0</version>
 </dependency>
 
 
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
     <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.0-rc4</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
     <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.0-rc4</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
     <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
     <version>2.1.5</version>
 </dependency>
 
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
     <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
     <version>1.3.1</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.dev.cassandra</groupId>
     <artifactId>spark-cassandra</artifactId>
     <version>1.0</version>
 </dependency>
 
 <dependency> 
     <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
     <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
     <version>2.10.3</version>
 </dependency>
 
 <dependency>
 <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
 <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
 <version>2.10.3</version>
 </dependency>
 <!--
 <dependency>
 <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
 <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
 <version>2.10.0-M1</version>
 </dependency>
 -->

  
 <!--
 
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
     <artifactId>scala-swing</artifactId>
     <version>2.10.0-M1</version>
 </dependency>
 -->
 
    </dependencies>
   

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
   
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.5</version>
                </plugin>
  <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
      <mainClass>com.dev.cassandra.Main</mainClass>
      <cleanupDaemonThreads>false</cleanupDaemonThreads>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
       </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Plugin to create a single jar that includes all dependencies 
            <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.dev.cassandra.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
   <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
  -->
        </plugins>
    </build>    

</project>
```

JAVA CODE:

```html
package com.dev.cassandra;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import java.sql.*;

import org.apache.spark.*;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.*; 
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;

import oracle.jdbc.*;

import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector;
import static com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraJavaUtil.*;

public class Main implements Serializable {

    private static final org.apache.log4j.Logger LOGGER = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Main.class);

    private static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    private static final String JDBC_USERNAME = "XXXXXO01";
    private static final String JDBC_PWD = "XXXXXO01";
    private static final String JDBC_CONNECTION_URL =
            "jdbc:oracle:thin:" + JDBC_USERNAME + "/" + JDBC_PWD + "@CONNECTION VALUES";

    private transient SparkConf conf;
  
    private Main(SparkConf conf) {
        this.conf = conf;
    }
  
    private void run() {
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
        generateData(sc);
        compute(sc);
        showResults(sc);
        sc.stop();
    }
  
    private void generateData(JavaSparkContext sc) {
    
      SQLContext sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc);
      System.out.println("AFTER SQL CONTEXT");
      
      //Data source options
      Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<>();
      options.put("driver", JDBC_DRIVER);
      options.put("url", JDBC_CONNECTION_URL);
      options.put("dbtable","(SELECT * FROM XXX_SAMPLE_TABLE WHERE ROWNUM <=5)");
      
      CassandraConnector connector = CassandraConnector.apply(sc.getConf());
      
      try{ 
 Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
  
 System.out.println("BEFORE jdbcDF"); 
  
        //Load JDBC query result as DataFrame
        DataFrame jdbcDF = sqlContext.load("jdbc", options);
        System.out.println("AFTER jdbcDF");

        List<Row> tableRows = jdbcDF.collectAsList();
        
        System.out.println("AFTER tableRows");

        for (Row tableRow : tableRows) {
     System.out.println();
            LOGGER.info(tableRow);
            System.out.println();
        }
        
 }catch(Exception e){
   //Handle errors for Class.forName
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
    }
  
    private void compute(JavaSparkContext sc) {
    }
  
    private void showResults(JavaSparkContext sc) {
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
    {
 
      if (args.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Syntax: com.datastax.spark.dev.cassandra <Spark Master URL> <Cassandra contact point>");
            System.exit(1);
        }
  
 //JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkJdbcDs").setMaster("local[*]"));
 SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkJdbcDs").setMaster("local[*]");

 
 //SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
        //conf.setAppName("SparkJdbcDs");
        //conf.setMaster(args[0]);
        //conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", args[1]);
  
        Main app = new Main(conf);
        app.run();
 
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Spark-Cassandra connector does not support Spark 1.3.x yet - See compatibility table: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector

Comment: Furthermore, your pom.xml is requesting the Scala 2.11 versions of the Spark JARs and the Scala 2.10 versions of the Cassandra JARs. (Based on the naming convention for Scala Artifact IDs, which end with the version of Scala you want them built for.) These need to be consistent (a) with each other and (b) with the Scala version you're actually using.

Comment: @SpiroMichaylov - Greatly appreciate the recommendation; my error, like you mention, was that i was calling the wrong Scala version (2.11) in my pom.xml.  After making the change to version 2.10 in my Spark dependency it worked. Thank you!

Comment: @maasg - Since the spark-cassandra-connector does not support Spark 1.3.x as of yet i probably wouldn't be able to use the DataFrame concept used in the post below to send/convert DataFrames to Cassandra correct? http://www.sparkexpert.com/2015/03/28/loading-database-data-into-spark-using-data-sources-api/

Comment: And no, alas you won't be able to use DataFrames, as they were introduced in 1.3.0. Also, the Cassandra connector's support for Spark SQL in general pre-dates the external datasource API introduced in Spark 1.2.0, so even when support for Spark 1.3.0 comes out it won't necessarily immediately support the approach described in the blog post you reference. (However, you can get similar functionality by using the [Spark SQL support](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/2_loading.md) -- search for "SQL".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pom.xml is requesting the Scala 2.11 versions of some of the Spark JARs

```
<artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>

<artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
```

and the Scala 2.10 versions of another Spark JAR and the Cassandra connector JARs.

```
<artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>

<artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>

<artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10</artifactId>
```

(Based on the naming convention for Scala Artifact IDs, which end with the version of Scala you want them built for.)

These need to be consistent (a) with each other and (b) with the Scala version you're actually using.